# Cannot get out of continuation prompt in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I was practicing some data entry in SQLite and I could not remove myself from the continuation prompt, even when ending with a semicolon.  Here is the code I used.

INSERT INTO quote (name, quote) VALUES('Acolyte of Pain', 'He trained when he was younger to be an acolyte of joy, but things didn't work out like he thought they would.');
...>
...>

After entering more text or ; it continues to show me.

...>

Why is it not working and how can I complete or exit the continuation prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unescaped "'" in a string; try:

```
INSERT INTO quote (name, quote) VALUES('Acolyte of Pain', 'He trained when he was younger to be an acolyte of joy, but things didn''t work out like he thought they would.');
```

(Note the doubled "''".)